# Define getter for child class variable inside parent

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism, parent-child

I have a project where I am accessing several classes using a pointer to a parent class. I need to know which child class the pointer is referring to, so I am adding a distinct integer ID number to each of them as a constant class variable.

I need to access this variable using the pointer, so I wrote a getter function for that variable. Since the code for the getter function would be the same for all of the child classes, I tried defining the function in the parent class. This roughly lead to the code found below:

```
class Parent {
  public:
    virtual void func();

    // Getter function
    uint8_t getID() {
      return classID;
    }

    // Set ID to a default value
    const uint8_t classID = 0;
};

// One of many child classes
class A: public Parent {
  public:
    void func() {//do something}

    const uint8_t classID = 1;
};

int main(){
    Parent* childPointer = new A;
    uint8_t currentID = childPointer -> getID();
}
```

However, running this led to `currentID` being equal to `Parent.classID` rather than `A.classID`.

Making the `getID` function virtual and definining it in each of the child classes made it work as intended, but this would lead to quite a bit of repeated code. I was wondering if there was a way to define the getter function once in the `Parent` class, and to make it return the correct value? Otherwise, is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ each class has it's own namespace. In your code you have a classID in the Parent namespace and a classID in the A namespace. So every instance of A actually has 2 classIDs. The getID() function only sees the classID in the Parent namespace though. This is why it only returns 0.

A better way would be to define constructors which will initialize the classID in Parent:

```
#include <cstdint>

class Parent {
  public:
    Parent(): classID(0){}; //Default Parent initializes with 0
    Parent(uint8_t ID): classID(ID){}; //Constructor to be called by children

    virtual void func(){};

    // Getter function
    uint8_t getID() {
      return classID;
    };

    const uint8_t classID;
};

// One of many child classes
class A: public Parent {
  public:
    A(): Parent(1){}; //Every A calls Parent(uint8_t) constructor

    void func() {};//do something

    //const uint8_t classID = 1;  //This is not needed anymore
};

int main(){
    Parent* childPointer = new A;
    uint8_t currentID = childPointer -> getID();
}
```